# Randomly change of characters in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to randomly change the case of a string to upcase or downcase.  There is a similar question on here for it except it doesn't guarantee that the string gets changed.

I am currently using:

```
def random_case_changes(string_to_change: string, change_case: 'downcase')
  raise ArgumentError, "Param is #{string_to_change.class}, not a string" unless string_to_change.is_a? String

  string_to_change.chars.map { |char| (rand 0..2).zero? ? char : char.send(change_case) }.join
end
```

`random_case_changes(string_to_change: 'Hello', change_case: 'upcase')`

There is a chance that this will just return `'Hello`.

I've looked at using `.sample` on the array of chars, but it jumbles the order and I haven't found a way to put the string back into it's original order after a change has been made.

Is there a way to guarantee that a change will take place?

Comment: What's `change_case`?

Comment: Philosophical question: If your string MUST change, is it truly random?

Comment: change_case is the second named param in the method with a default value of downcase

Comment: The naming has been tricky as it's a mandatory change of random characters within a string.  Linting rules are making it difficult to write an apt name

Comment: How about? : `string_to_change.public_send(change_case) if string_to_change.respond_to?(change_case)`

Comment: A string will respond to both upcase and downcase regardless of it's current case

Comment: What if you chose 'downcase' but the `string_to_change` is already all downcase? It will never change.

Comment: Also `rand(0..2)` will return `0`, `1` or `2`. So checking for `zero?` will only return `true` in one third of the cases.

Comment: @KarlNicoll, certainly! In probability terms, there is sample space that contains all strings formed by reversing or not the case of each character of the given string, except for the string so-produced that equals the given string. We are to randomly draw a member of that sample space. Conceptually, this is no different than adding the given string to this sample space and then choosing a member at random.

Comment: Yes, there's a chance that `'Hello'` will be returned. If your string has length `n`, that probability is `1 / 2**n`. You want `rand 0...2`, or `rand 0..1` or `[0, 1].sample`, but not `rand 0..2`, which can return `2`.

Comment: As I understand, you want to first specify "downcase" or "upcase". Assume it is "upcase".  Then you go through the string and set each character to "upcase" (even if it's already upcase) with probability 0.5, and you want the resulting string to differ from the original string. Correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Insightful, thanks!

Comment: Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to guarantee that a change will take place?

You could get the indices of the character that *could* change, e.g. the lowercase ones:

```
string_to_change = 'Hello'

indices = string_to_change.enum_for(:scan, /[[:lower:]]/).map { $~.begin(0) }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And out of this array pick between 1 and all elements that *will* change: (the order doesn't matter)

```
indices_to_be_changed = indices.sample(rand(1..indices.size))
#=> [4, 2]
```

Now all you have to do is swap the case of the corresponding characters: (upper to lower or vice-versa)

```
indices_to_be_changed.each do |i|
  string_to_change[i] = string_to_change[i].swapcase
end

string_to_change
#=> "HeLlO"
```

Comment: are you able to explain what ```{ $~.begin(0) }``` is doing please? I am guessing it is mapping starting at zero?

Comment: I've read some Ruby documentation and I get what it is doing.  Thank you, this solution is great.

Comment: What about "HELLO"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland that case can be handled by checking whether `indices` is empty. I assumed that there’s at least one possible result.

Comment: Tom, [$~](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/globalvars.html) is the [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html) object for the last regex match (`$~.class #=> MatchData)`. Therefore, `$~.begin(0)` is element of the match array (here there's but one) at index `0`. See [MatchData#begin](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html#method-i-begin). You can alternatively write `Regexp.last_match.begin(0)`, which is more self-documenting. See [Regexp::last_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def random_case_changes(string: string, case: 'downcase')
  if string.is_a?(String)
    string.chars.map { |char| [char, char.public_send(change_case)].sample }.join
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "Param is #{string.class}, not a string"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways that could be done that ensure [pseudo-randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness).

All use the string

```
str = "WoLf"
```

for demonstration and the method

```
def change_possible?(str, to_case)
  str.count(to_case == :downcase ? 'a-z' : 'A-Z') < str.size       
end
```

to determine if the randomization procedure can produce a string that is different than the given string, `str`.

```
change_possible?("WoLf", :downcase) #=> true
change_possible?("WoLf", :upcase)   #=> true
```

```
change_possible?('wolf', :downcase) #=> false
change_possible?('WOLF', :upcase)   #=> false
```

The latter two approaches use the method

```
def char_case(c)
  c.downcase == c ? :downcase : :upcase
end
```

```
char_case('a') #=> :downcase
char_case('A') #=> :upcase
```

**Change the case of one randomly-selected character then randomly determine whether to set the case of each of the remaining characters to the specified case**<sup>1</sup>

```
def scramble(str, to_case)
  return nil unless change_possible?(str, to_case)
  i = str.size.times.reject do |i|
    char_case(str[i]) == to_case
  end.sample
  c = str[i].public_send(to_case)
  str.gsub(/./) { |s| [s, s.public_send(to_case)].sample }.
      tap { |s| s[i] = c }
end
```

```
str                         #=> "WoLf" 
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "Wolf" 
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "woLf" 
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "wolf" 
scramble("wolf", :downcase) #=> nil
```

```
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WOLF" 
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WOLf"
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WOLF" 
scramble("WOLF", :upcase)   #=> nil
```

**Randomly determine whether to set the case of each character to the specified case, repeating until the resulting string differs from the given string**

```
def scramble(str, to_case)
  return nil unless change_possible?(str, to_case)
  loop do
    s = str.gsub(/./) { |c| [c, c.public_send(to_case)].sample }
    break s unless s == str
  end
end
```

```
str                         #=> "WoLf" 
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "Wolf" 
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "woLf"  
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "wolf" 
scramble("wolf", :downcase) #=> nil
```

```
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WOLF" 
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WoLF" 
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WoLF" 
scramble("WOLF", :upcase)   #=> nil
```

Note that `c.public_send(to_case)` may equal `c` in `[c, c.public_send(to_case)].sample`.

**Construct the sample space then select a member at random**

```
def scramble(str, to_case)
  return nil unless change_possible?(str, to_case)
  sample_space(str, to_case).sample
end

def sample_space(str, to_case)
  fixed_idx = str.size.times.select do |i|
    char_case(str[i]) == to_case
  end
  len = str.size
  (0..2**str.size - 1).map do |n|
    len.times.with_object('') do |i,s|
      s << (n[i] == 1 ? str[i].upcase : str[i].downcase)
    end
  end.reject do |s|
    s == str || fixed_idx.any? { |i| s[i] != str[i] }
  end
end
```

```
str                         #=> "WoLf" 
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "wolf" 
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "woLf" 
scramble(str, :downcase)    #=> "Wolf"
scramble("wolf", :downcase) #=> nil
```

```
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WOLF" 
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WOLF" 
scramble(str, :upcase)      #=> "WoLF"
scramble("WOLF", :upcase)   #=> nil
```

For `:downcase` the sample space was found to be

```
["wolf", "Wolf", "woLf"]
```

For `:upcase`,

```
["WOLf", "WoLF", "WOLF"]
```

The sample space initially contains `2**str.size #=> 16` elements, there being a 1-1 map between each element of the sample space and one of the integers between `0` and `2**str.size - 1`. The mapping corresponds to the value of the integer's bits (padded with leading zeroes, when necessary, to `str.size` bits), `0` corresponding to lowercase, `1` to uppercase. Invalid strings are then removed from the sample space.

See [Integer#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D) and note that `n[i]` can equal `0`, `1` or `nil`, with `nil` corresponding to a leading `0`.

I make no claims about the efficiency of this approach.

<sup>1. This is a variant of Stefan's approach.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input.  These answers pushed me down a rabbit hole of learning and investigation.

Here is the solution I went with:

```
def random_case_change(string, options = {})
  new_case = options[:new_case].nil? ? 'upcase' : options[:new_case]

  # don't attempt to change if string is ONLY whitespace
  unless string.match?(/\A\s*\z/)
    # only word characters will be changed,
    string.chars.each_with_index.map { |c, idx| c.match?(/\w/) ? idx : nil }.reject(&:nil?)
        .then { |indicies| indicies.sample(rand(1..indicies.size)) }
        .inject(string) { |memo, idx| memo[idx] = memo[idx].send(new_case); memo }
  end
  string
end
```

I took it further to ignore the string if it is only whitespace. It will also ignore any characters in the string that are not word characters. I also added a default option to the kind of I wish to use.  This will allow, upcase, downcase and swapcase.